# Send 2d array from java servlet to javascript

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

There is a solution for passing a single dimension array from a java servlet to javascript by using `Arrays.toString(data)`.

What are the solutions for sending a 2d array? The above solution does not work. So far I have this in my doGet function:

```
res.setContentType("text/html");
res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
res.getWriter().write(Arrays.toString(db.createLayer(iterable)));
```

A solution for retrieving the data in javascript would also be great(unless it's just doing two simple for-loops). I'm using jquery's `$.get` function.

Comment: Because that was not what I asked, unless the only option is to use JSON.